# Creating string and using it as the name of the output file

Tags: string, scheme, lisp, fluent, ansys

I have no experience in Scheme programming, but I need to write a few lines for my Fluent simulation. I have the following loop:

```
 (Do ((x 1 (+ x 1))) ((> x 150))
 (physical-time-steps 10 20)
 (wd flow.dat)
 )
```

In each iteration, it solves the problem and then writes the result to the file "flow.dat". The problem is that it overwrites the solution in each iteration, so I need to create a string in each iteration e.g. "flow1.dat","flow2.dat","flow3.dat",... and use them as the name of my output file. Could you please let me know how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the `x` variable to append a number to the file's name, like this:

```
(wd (string-append "flow" (number->string x) ".dat"))
```